# How do I test a warp filter with multiple websocket clients?

Tags: testing, rust, websocket, rust-tokio, warp

I am trying to connect multiple test clients to one server / filter. I tried:

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_ws() {
    let mut client1 = warp::test::ws()
        .path("/api/ws/test")
        .handshake(get_server())
        .await
        .expect("handshake");
    let mut client2 = warp::test::ws()
        .path("/api/ws/test")
        .handshake(get_server())
        .await
        .expect("handshake");
```

The `get_server` functions returns a `BoxedFilter` that i want to test. I tried storing it and borrowing it but that didn’t work. This currently creates a new test server for each client. I want the clients to connect to the same test server.

Answer (score 0):

Any warp `Filter` should implement `Clone`, which includes [`BoxedFilter`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.2/warp/filters/struct.BoxedFilter.html). So you should create the "server" once and clone it for each test client:

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_ws() {
    let server = get_server();

    let mut client1 = warp::test::ws()
        .path("/api/ws/test")
        .handshake(server.clone())
        .await
        .expect("handshake");

    let mut client2 = warp::test::ws()
        .path("/api/ws/test")
        .handshake(server.clone())
        .await
        .expect("handshake");

    // ... test away!
}
```